# How to convert a datetime format to minutes - pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, series

I have a data frame which has a column usage_duration (which is the difference of two another columns in datetime format). It looks like below:

```
processid, userid, usage_duration 
17613,root,0 days 23:41:03.000000000
17641,root,2 days 04:05:26.000000000
13848,acs,0 days 00:00:50.000000000
3912,acs,0 days 06:07:38.000000000
6156,acs,0 days 17:22:43.000000000
```

Now I wanted to convert the same into minutes. It should look like as below:

```
processid, userid, usage_duration_min
17613,root,1421
17641,root,3125
13848,acs,0
3912,acs,367
6156,acs,1042
```

Can someone let me know how is it possible?

Highly appreciate your support

Comment: Another way more general maybe the one reporte here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html) or [`seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timedelta.seconds.html) and divide by `60`, last cast to `integer`s:

```
#if necessary converting to timedelta
#df['usage_duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['usage_duration'])

df['new'] = df['usage_duration'].dt.total_seconds().div(60).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
 df['new'] = (df['usage_duration'].dt.seconds.div(60).astype(int) 
             + df['usage_duration'].dt.days.multiply(1440).astype(int) )

print (df)
   processid userid  usage_duration   new
0      17613   root 0 days 23:41:03  1421
1      17641   root 2 days 04:05:26  3125
2      13848    acs 0 days 00:00:50     0
3       3912    acs 0 days 06:07:38   367
4       6156    acs 0 days 17:22:43  1042
```

Comment: This suggestion works, but the 2 days are not converting. For example in the second row, it is only converting 04:05:26

Comment: df['new'] = df['usage_duration'].dt.seconds.div(60).astype(int)+df['usage_duration'].dt.days.multiply(1440).astype(int)

Comment: @JitheshErancheri - Thank you, I change answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is one way:

```
s = pd.Series(['0 days 23:41:03.000000000', '2 days 04:05:26.000000000',
               '0 days 00:00:50.000000000', '0 days 06:07:38.000000000',
               '0 days 17:22:43.000000000'])

s = pd.to_timedelta(s).astype('timedelta64[m]').astype(int)

print(s)

0    1421
1    3125
2       0
3     367
4    1042
dtype: int32
```