# calculate the time difference between two consecutive rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows

```
Dev_id     Time
88345      13:40:31
87556      13:20:33
88955      13:05:00
.....      ........
85678      12:15:28
```

The above dataframe has 83000 rows. I want to take time difference between two consecutive rows and keep it in a separate column. The desired result would be

```
Dev_id    Time          Time_diff(in min)
88345      13:40:31      20
87556      13:20:33      15
88955      13:05:00      15
```

I have tried `df['Time_diff'] = df['Time'].diff(-1)` but getting error as shown below

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

How to solve this

Comment: [Calculate Pandas DataFrame Time Difference Between Two Columns in Hours and Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22923775/7758804) is an associated question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Problem is `pandas` need `datetime`s or `timedelta`s for `diff` function, so first converting by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), then get [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and divide by `60`:

```
df['Time_diff'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str)).diff(-1).dt.total_seconds().div(60)
#alternative
#df['Time_diff'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'].astype(str)).diff(-1).dt.total_seconds().div(60)
print (df)
   Dev_id      Time  Time_diff
0   88345  13:40:31  19.966667
1   87556  13:20:33  15.550000
2   88955  13:05:00  49.533333
3   85678  12:15:28        NaN
```

If want [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) per minutes:

```
df['Time_diff'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))
                     .diff(-1)
                     .dt.floor('T')
                     .dt.total_seconds()
                     .div(60))
print (df)
   Dev_id      Time  Time_diff
0   88345  13:40:31       19.0
1   87556  13:20:33       15.0
2   88955  13:05:00       49.0
3   85678  12:15:28        NaN
```

Comment: can't it be `df['Time_diff'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])).diff(-1).dt.floor('T').dt.total_seconds().div(60)` , i believe we don't require `astype(str) , or First convert `df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])` then `df['Time_Diff'] = df['Time'].diff(-1).dt.total_seconds().div(60)` Just a thought.

Comment: @pygo - problem is with error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'` - it means there are times, no strings, so necessary convering. For testing `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time`

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert / cast df['Time'] column to `pd.Timedelta` and then do the substraction