# Time difference between two event rows for each user in Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
    imei    event_type               time   
    1107    alarm                    2020-01-28 11:32:42+00:00  
    1107    alarm_restored           2020-01-28 11:32:53+00:00
    1107    alarm_emergency          2020-01-28 11:33:03+00:00  
    1107    alarm_emergency_restored 2020-01-28 11:33:06+00:00
    1108    alarm                    2020-01-28 11:42:42+00:00  
    1108    alarm_restored           2020-01-28 11:43:53+00:00
    1109    alarm_emergency          2020-01-28 11:53:23+00:00  
    1109    alarm_emergency          2020-01-28 11:53:23+00:00  
    1109    alarm_emergency_restored 2020-01-28 11:57:06+00:00  
    1110    alarm_emergency          2020-01-29 10:23:05+00:00  
    1111    alarm_restored           2020-01-29 11:10:53+00:00  
    1112    alarm_emergency_restored 2020-01-29 12:13:23+00:00
```

I want to find the time difference between alarm and restored type events for every user.
I have no idea how to proceed with it. 
I tried [calculate the time difference between two consecutive rows in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020248/calculate-the-time-difference-between-two-consecutive-rows-in-pandas)
I tried

```
    df_alarm['time'].diff(3)
```

and got :

```
    0                              NaT
    1                              NaT
    2                              NaT
    3           0 days 00:00:23.706000
    4           0 days 00:27:28.364000
    ...
```

Which is not how I expected the results.
I want results in minutes/seconds

UPDATE:

I want to find time difference in every consecutive alarm and alarm_restored, alarm_emergency and alarm_emergency_restored only if they are consecutive rows. All other rows should be NaT.

Expected Output:

```
    imei    event_type               time                       time_diff
    1107    alarm                    2020-01-28 11:32:42+00:00  NaT
    1107    alarm_restored           2020-01-28 11:32:53+00:00  00:00:11
    1107    alarm_emergency          2020-01-28 11:33:03+00:00  NaT
    1107    alarm_emergency_restored 2020-01-28 11:33:06+00:00  00:00:03
    1108    alarm                    2020-01-28 11:42:42+00:00  NaT
    1108    alarm_restored           2020-01-28 11:43:53+00:00  00:01:11
    1109    alarm_emergency          2020-01-28 11:14:27+00:00  NaT
    1109    alarm_emergency          2020-01-28 11:53:23+00:00  NaT
    1109    alarm_emergency_restored 2020-01-28 11:57:06+00:00  00:03:43
    1110    alarm_emergency          2020-01-29 10:23:05+00:00  NaT
    1111    alarm_restored           2020-01-29 11:10:53+00:00  NaT
    1112    alarm_emergency_restored 2020-01-29 12:13:23+00:00  NaT
```

As you see, if there are two consecutive alarm_* events and one restoral after that(as in rows 1109-1109), I want to find difference only between row 2 and row 3 for 1109.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

First you get the time difference between all the rows.

```
df["timediff"] = df.groupby(df.imei)["time"].diff()
```

Then, you just set timediff to NaT (not a time) for all rows that are not "*_restored" because you don't care about the time from "*_restored" to any other alarm events:

```
import numpy as np
df["timediff"][df.event_type.str.contains("restored") == False] = np.datetime64('NaT')
```

This gives exactly what you want.

Comment: other rows are not irrelevant. I need difference between every type of alarm, for every user.

Comment: @Rasika You said "I want to find the time difference between alarm and restored type events". So you want time difference between alarm and each of `alarm_*`? You should provide your expected output from the example given.

Comment: Yes. My bad. I should have been more clear. But thanks for your solution. I am trying it.

Comment: I have updated my expected output. Your solution is not what I was expected. I was not very clear in my question. Hence updated it with expected output now.

Comment: This wont work for me Have added edits. Please have a look

Comment: @Rasika Does `imei` serve as group? In imei 1110, you are calculating time difference between two differen imeis.\

Comment: If that's the case, I don't see why mine is not working. It's working for me with the data you provided. I'm getting exactly the same as your expected.

Comment: @Rasika Only thing might be affecting could be I had imei as index, so I was grouping by `df.index`.

Comment: This works best after changing to groupby imei. Thanks!