# Pandas filter out events that do not take place within x amount of time of each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe of events by users, and I want to keep any events that have taken place within a given time (e.g. 2 hours) of each other, that are associated to the same user and the same store. Here is an example dataframe:

| user_id | timestamp | store_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | 2021-11-26T13:40:00.000Z | store_1 |
| user_1 | 2021-11-26T12:20:00.000Z | store_1 |
| user_1 | 2021-11-22T16:10:00.000Z | store_1 |
| user_2 | 2021-11-19T22:00:00.000Z | store_2 |
| user_2 | 2021-11-19T19:50:00.000Z | store_2 |
| user_3 | 2021-11-28T06:10:00.000Z | store_1 |
| user_4 | 2021-11-18T16:30:00.000Z | store_3 |
| user_4 | 2021-11-18T16:20:00.000Z | store_2 |

Applying the filtering, the ouput dataframe should look like this:

| user_id | timestamp | store_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | 2021-11-26T13:40:00.000Z | store_1 |
| user_1 | 2021-11-26T12:20:00.000Z | store_1 |

Because only the first two events by `user_1` took place at the same store, by the same user, and within 2 hours of one another. I have been searching through stackoverflow questions, but nothing seems to fit this scenario. Any help would be really appreciated!

EDIT: Following [Time difference between two event rows for each user in Pandas df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60625263/time-difference-between-two-event-rows-for-each-user-in-pandas-df), I am calculating the time difference between rows, grouped by user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Sort by `timestamp`:

   ```
   df = df.sort_values('timestamp')
   ```
2. [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the user+store and check if the time [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) (forward or backward) is within the specified `delta`:

   <sub>(Note that `keep` is shown here as a column only for explanation purposes. This code doesn't actually add it as a column, though it's also fine to make it a column if preferred.)</sub>

   ```
   delta = pd.Timedelta('2H')

   keep = (df.groupby(['user_id', 'store_id'], sort=False)['timestamp']
       .transform(lambda g: g.diff().abs().le(delta) | g.diff(-1).abs().le(delta)))

   #    user_id                  timestamp  store_id   keep
   # 7   user_4  2021-11-18 16:20:00+00:00   store_2  False
   # 6   user_4  2021-11-18 16:30:00+00:00   store_3  False
   # 4   user_2  2021-11-19 19:50:00+00:00   store_2  False
   # 3   user_2  2021-11-19 22:00:00+00:00   store_2  False
   # 2   user_1  2021-11-22 16:10:00+00:00   store_1  False
   # 1   user_1  2021-11-26 12:20:00+00:00   store_1   True
   # 0   user_1  2021-11-26 13:40:00+00:00   store_1   True
   # 5   user_3  2021-11-28 06:10:00+00:00   store_1  False
   ```
3. Filter with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or slicing:

   ```
   df.loc[keep]  # or df[keep]

   #    user_id                  timestamp  store_id
   # 1   user_1  2021-11-26 12:20:00+00:00   store_1
   # 0   user_1  2021-11-26 13:40:00+00:00   store_1
   ```