# Calculate time difference in Hours or seconds between two columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I am trying to calculate machine downtime in a python code which is predominantly pandas dataframe manipulation. If a repair number starts during any of the days then I have take take time bewteen start of the day and start of the work order as my machine available time. I have created the column for day start time as  in every row which is at a day level granularity so that when there is a repair order I just need to subtract two time fields to get my answer in seconds/hours. But I am currently getting error as 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'astype'. I tried out of a few options suggested here but to no vail. I know I am doing somehting very fundamentally wrong, please point me in the right directions.

```
for i, row in df4.iterrows():
    if (row['Date'] == row['START_DATE']) | (row['Date'] == row['END_DATE']):
        if (row['START_DATE'] == row['Date']) & (row['END_DATE'] != row['Date']):

            value = pd.to_timedelta(row.REPAIR_START-row.Date_start).astype('timedelta64[h]')
            df4.set_value(i,'avail',value)

        if (row['START_DATE'] != row['Date']) & (row['END_DATE'] == row['Date']):

            value = pd.to_timedelta((row.REPAIR_FINISH-row.Date_end)).astype('timedelta64[h]')
            df4.set_value(i,'avail',value)

        if (row['START_DATE'] == row['Date']) & (row['END_DATE'] == row['Date']):
            value = pd.to_timedelta((row.REPAIR_START-row.REPAIR_FINISH)).astype('timedelta64[h]')
            df4.set_value(i,'avail',value)
        else: df4.set_value(i,'avail',full_day)
```

Data is at Machine , Date level. Explanation of the metadata of the code:
Date : Daily date
START_DATE : Only date part of the repair timestamp
END_DATE : Only date part of the repair timestamp
REPAIR_START : Repair order start timestamp
REPAIR_START  : Repair order end timestamp

Comment: By just giving : value = (row.REPAIR_FINISH-row.Date_end)           ;  I am able to get a time value : 0 days 11:59:59 but i need it in hours or seconds .

Comment: value is of type timedelta, it has a method called total_seconds() it returns it in seconds. value =  (row.REPAIR_FINISH-row.Date_end).total_seconds()

Comment: It is working !! Much Obliged.

Comment: Great, you're welcome !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate Pandas DataFrame Time Difference Between Two Columns in Hours and Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu)