# How to calculate the time (in seconds) difference between two DateTime columns using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

A pandas DataFrame (df3) has contained two columns contain timedelta64[ns] as shown. How can you calculate the difference time of them in seconds in a new column?

```
[In][1] df3.head()
Out[1]
```

[image: Subset of df3]

The new df3 should be like:

[image: exactly what I needed!]

how do I get difference in total seconds?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate Pandas DataFrame Time Difference Between Two Columns in Hours and Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu)

Answer (score 4):

We can use `total_seconds`

```
(df.dropoff_datetime-df.pickup_datetime).dt.total_seconds()
Out[514]: 
0    1327.0
1    2040.0
2    1680.0
3    1975.0
4    3083.0
dtype: float64
df['diff']= (df.dropoff_datetime-df.pickup_datetime).dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: But I need time without (.), just like 1327 & 2040 & 1680 &

Comment: `(df.dropoff_datetime-df.pickup_datetime).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)` @M_Fatih89