# Time difference between two columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

How can I subtract the time between two columns and convert it to minutes

```
         Date Time Ordered Time Delivered
0  1/11/19   9:25:00 am    10:58:00 am
1  1/11/19  10:16:00 am    11:13:00 am
2  1/11/19  10:25:00 am    10:45:00 am
3  1/11/19  10:45:00 am    11:12:00 am
4  1/11/19  11:11:00 am    11:47:00 am
```

I want to subtract the Time_delivered - Time_ordered to get the minutes the delivery took.

```
df.time_ordered = pd.to_datetime(df.time_ordered)
```

This doesn't output the correct time instead it adds today's date the time

Comment: Please post the data as text and not an image. No one can copy it into python if its an image. Also in your image your column name is `Time Ordered` but in your code you imply it is `time_ordered`...

Comment: What does `pd.to_datetime(df.["Date"] + df["Time Ordered"])` give you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate Pandas DataFrame Time Difference Between Two Columns in Hours and Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert both time columns to datetimes, get difference, convert to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and then to minutes by division by `60`:

```
df['diff'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.time_ordered, format='%I:%M:%S %p')
                .sub(pd.to_datetime(df.time_delivered, format='%I:%M:%S %p'))
                .dt.total_seconds()
                .div(60))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to_datetime()

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['9:25:00 AM','10:58:00 AM']],
                  columns=['time1', 'time2'])

print(pd.to_datetime(df.time2)-pd.to_datetime(df.time1))
```

Output:

```
01:33:00
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is using `np.timedelta64`

```
print(df)
     Date Time Ordered Time Delivered
0  1/11/19   9:25:00 am    10:58:00 am
1  1/11/19  10:16:00 am    11:13:00 am
2  1/11/19  10:25:00 am    10:45:00 am
3  1/11/19  10:45:00 am    11:12:00 am
4  1/11/19  11:11:00 am    11:47:00 am

   df['mins'] =  (
    pd.to_datetime(df["Date"] + " " + df["Time Delivered"])
    - pd.to_datetime(df["Date"] + " " + df["Time Ordered"])
) / np.timedelta64(1, "m")
```

output:

```
print(df)
   Date     Time Ordered   Time Delivered mins
0  1/11/19   9:25:00 am    10:58:00 am  93.0
1  1/11/19  10:16:00 am    11:13:00 am  57.0
2  1/11/19  10:25:00 am    10:45:00 am  20.0
3  1/11/19  10:45:00 am    11:12:00 am  27.0
4  1/11/19  11:11:00 am    11:47:00 am  36.0
```