# Difference between two date columns in a dataframe using python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two columns in a dataframe in the format that it contains date and time as well. I need to find the difference in hours. When I try its giving type error.

Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'.

```
Data example:

D1: 12/26/2014 7:45
    12/31/2014 6:30
D2: 1/1/2015 2:18
    1/1/2015 2:49
```

Need to find difference as D1-D2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate Pandas DataFrame Time Difference Between Two Columns in Hours and Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu)

Answer (score 1):

str function doesn't support it, you need to turn it into datetime format, look up about datetime module in python

official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html