# Python datetime still gives "TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'"

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This code has been working for me for months and this morning it is throwing the error: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
dt=datetime.datetime.strptime

date_array=[]
for i in range(len(Date)):
    date_array.append(dt(Date[i],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')) # Data downloaded with obtimezone=local
date_array=n.array(date_array)

# Wire Mountain Dataframe
W_data=pd.DataFrame(data={'Solar':WIRC1},index=date_array)
W_mask=W_data.where(W_data > 0) # Using only daytime data, when solar does not equal 0
W_mean=W_mask.resample('D').mean() #Daily mean
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
                           Solar
2020-10-25 00:50:00-07:00    0.0
2020-10-25 01:50:00-07:00    0.0
2020-10-25 02:50:00-07:00    0.0
2020-10-25 03:50:00-07:00    0.0
2020-10-25 04:50:00-07:00    0.0
2020-10-25 05:50:00-07:00    0.0
2020-10-25 06:50:00-07:00    0.0
2020-10-25 07:50:00-07:00    2.0
2020-10-25 08:50:00-07:00   49.0
2020-10-25 09:50:00-07:00  116.0
2020-10-25 10:50:00-07:00  155.0
2020-10-25 11:50:00-07:00  233.0
2020-10-25 12:50:00-07:00  363.0
```

The array I used as an index for the dataframe is python datetime

```
type(date_array[0])
Out[24]: datetime.datetime
```

Why did this suddenly stop working? Maybe backend code on Pandas changing? I thought maybe I could change the python datetime index to Pandas using:

```
date_array=n.array(pd.to_datetime(date_array))
```

But got:

```
ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

I also tried from another Stack Overflow question:

```
W_mean=W_mask.set_index(date_array).resample('D').mean()
```

But I got the same error. Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Why do you want to use Python datetime at all? Why not directly use pandas to_datetime? And I'd also suggest to convert the UTC offset to UTC, with keyword `utc=True`.

Comment: @MrFuppes - I ended up using Pandas for the datetime instead of Python. See explanation below. I'm fairly new to Pandas, so unfortunately my code ends of being a mishmash of Python and Pandas.

Comment: no worries, good you solved it, and it's good to know your way around Python's standard lib `datetime`, but in `pandas` you'll primarily want to use pandas built-ins ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "something" that changed was the local time- from daylight savings to standard. From [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63495502/creating-pandas-datetimeindex-in-dataframe-from-dst-aware-datetime-objects),

> A pandas datetime column also requires the offset to be the same. A
> column with different offsets, will not be converted to a datetime
> dtype. I suggest, do not convert the data to a datetime until it's in
> pandas.

My data had two offsets, as shown below:

```
Date[0]
Out[34]: '2020-10-25T00:50:00-0700'

Date[-1]
Out[35]: '2020-11-07T22:50:00-0800'
```

Because of the two different offsets, the dates were not being converted to a datetime dtype.

I pulled the data in UTC instead of local time, then as suggested, I did not convert to datetime until the date column was in Pandas. After adding the conversion to US/Pacific time, Pandas handled the time change seamlessly.

```
import pandas as pd
Date=n.genfromtxt('WIRC1.txt',delimiter=',',skip_header=8,usecols=1,dtype=str)

W_data=pd.DataFrame(data={'Solar':WIRC1},index=pd.to_datetime(Date).tz_convert('US/Pacific'))
W_mask=W_data.where(W_data > 0) # Using only daytime data, when solar does not equal 0
W_mean=W_mask.resample('D').mean() #Daily mean
```