# How to convert time in days, hours, minutes, and seconds to only seconds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-analysis

I have the following dataframe column:

[image: Columm of Dataset]

I need to convert object string data from the csv column into total seconds.

Example: 10m -> 600s

---

I tried this code:

```
df.duration = str(datetime.timedelta(df['duration']))
```

But the following error is displayed

> TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series

Answer (score 3):

- The correct, and vectorized way to convert `'duration'` to seconds is to:

  1. Convert `'duration'` to a timedelta
  2. Divide by `pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)`
- The correct way to get seconds for only the hours, minutes and seconds component is to use `.dt.seconds`
- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63514967) for a thorough discussion of `timedelta` and why the `.total_seconds` method is a total accident.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'duration': ['10d 15h 23m', '10d 18h 13m']})

# convert duration to a timedelta
df.duration = pd.to_timedelta(df.duration)

# calculate total_seconds
df['total_sec'] =  df.duration / pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)

# get seconds for just hours, minutes, seconds
df['sec_without_days'] = df.duration.dt.seconds

# display(df)
          duration  total_sec  sec_without_days
0 10 days 15:23:00   919380.0             55380
1 10 days 18:13:00   929580.0             65580
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pandas.to_timedelta()` to convert your strings to timedelta objects and then apply a lambda function to get the total seconds in the duration:

```
import pandas as pd
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration']).apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())
```

Comment: @Trenton McKinney & @Thi-Cav: I updated my answer with the correct solution. (`x.seconds` is now changed to `x.total_seconds()`)