# Given a birthday column, how to calculate a persons age for the current day?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

### `vanco.csv`

```py
firstname,secondname,birthdate
vanco,grizov,3-16-1983
vlado,stojanov,6-24-1982
goce,grizov,7-18-1985
```

### Code

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

data=pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test\\vanco.csv')
data.head(3)
print(data)

data.birthdate=pd.to_datetime(data.birthdate)
data.head(3)
print (data)

def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))


data['birthdate'].apply(lambda x: calculate_age(x))
print(data)
```

From a code I have this output in PyCharm

[image]

I write the code then the column in csv file **birthdate** I convert to datetime object:

then I write a function to create and return the ages from `birthdate`

```py
def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))

data['birthdate'].apply(lambda x: calculate_age(x))
print(data)
```

From the code I have this output in the PyCharm console

```
filename secondname  birthdate
0    vanco     grizov  3-16-1983
1    vlado   stojanov  6-24-1982
2     goce     grizov  7-18-1985
  filename secondname  birthdate
0    vanco     grizov 1983-03-16
1    vlado   stojanov 1982-06-24
2     goce     grizov 1985-07-18
  filename secondname  birthdate
0    vanco     grizov 1983-03-16
1    vlado   stojanov 1982-06-24
2     goce     grizov 1985-07-18
```

- The expected output is a column with the age, should be added to the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This answer assumes the desired output is the age, in years, from the birthday until today.
- `(today - bd)` returns a value in total number of days.

  - Divide by `pd.Timedelta(days=365.25)`, to get the number of years.

    - `365.25` because the length of a year changes
- See [Calculate Pandas DataFrame Time Difference Between Two Columns in Hours and Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63514967) for additional details about timedeltas and converting to different time units.
- The original function returns a value, but the returned values aren't assigned back to the dataframe, with something like `df['age (years)'] = calc_age(df.birthdate)`, which is why the values show up in the console.
- Also, there is no need to use `.apply`. This applies the function iteratively, and is why there are multiple outputs to the console.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

# read the file in and covert the birthdate column to a datetime
df = pd.read_csv('vanco.csv', parse_dates=['birthdate'])

# function
def calc_age(bd: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    today = pd.to_datetime(date.today())  # convert today to a pandas datetime
    return (today - bd) / pd.Timedelta(days=365.25)  # divide by days to get years


# call function and assign the values to a new column in the dataframe
df['age (years)'] = calc_age(df.birthdate)

# display(df)
  firstname secondname  birthdate  age (years)
0     vanco     grizov 1983-03-16     37.48118
1     vlado   stojanov 1982-06-24     38.20671
2      goce     grizov 1985-07-18     35.14031
```

### Alternatively

- Use the [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module, which has a more feature rich selection of methods

  - [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) will compensate for leap years
  - Use `.years` to extract only the year component, from the `relativedelta` object.

```
# updated function with relativedelta
def calc_age(bd: pd.Series):
    today = pd.to_datetime(date.today())
    return bd.apply(lambda x: relativedelta(today, x).years)


# function call
df['age (years)'] = calc_age(df.birthdate)

# display(df)
  firstname secondname  birthdate  age (years)
0     vanco     grizov 1983-03-16           37
1     vlado   stojanov 1982-06-24           38
2      goce     grizov 1985-07-18           35

# the output if .years is removed from the calc_age function
  firstname secondname  birthdate                                    age (years)
0     vanco     grizov 1983-03-16  relativedelta(years=+37, months=+5, days=+22)
1     vlado   stojanov 1982-06-24  relativedelta(years=+38, months=+2, days=+14)
2      goce     grizov 1985-07-18  relativedelta(years=+35, months=+1, days=+20)
```

Comment: yes is working perfect Thanks I learn lot from you code Thanks Trenton