# How to calculate the number of days from a datetime until today?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe with a date column that is represented as ndarray object. I want to clusterize dataframe and I decided to convert each string (like '2009-01-04') in this column to int. How can I represent it as a recency in days considering the last date as today's date? I got some problems with "to_datetime" method.

```
index col1 col2  date
 0     a    34  '2009-01-04'
 1     a    21  '2009-01-05'
 2     b    8   '2009-01-06'
```

Thank you

Comment: Associated question [Calculate Pandas DataFrame Time Difference Between Two Columns in Hours and Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need convert dates to datetimes and then subtract from right side by [`Series.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html) today dates, last convert output timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).rsub(pd.Timestamp('now').floor('d')).dt.days
print (df)
  col1  col2          date   new
0    a    34  '2009-01-04'  4282
1    a    21  '2009-01-05'  4281
2    b     8  '2009-01-06'  4280
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, but got problems with converting timestap to int. Thank you for the answer.