# Subtract two datetime.time

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

i basicly need to get actual time(time1) and see how many hours and minutos to time2.
Its a countdown, how many time untill time2.

I have been making this

```
def schedule_task():
    exp_h = 23 
    exp_m = 5
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    if len(str(exp_m))==1:
        exp_m=str("0")+str(exp_m)

    date_time_str = str(exp_h)+":"+str(exp_m)+":00"
    exp_now = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str,"%H:%M:%S").time()
    fdate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    locl_h = now.strftime("%H")
    locl_m = now.strftime("%M")

    remain = datetime.datetime.combine(now.today(), fdate.time()) - datetime.datetime.combine(now.today(), exp_now)

    lbl_remaing.config(text="Request will be sent in "+str(remain), bg="darkgrey",fg="blue")

    if locl_h.strip()==exp_h.strip() and locl_m.strip()==exp_m.strip():
        print("run func")
    else:
        lbl_remaing.after(1000, schedule_task)
```

Having this error

> print("----> ",datetime.datetime.combine(now.today(), fdate.time())
>
> - datetime.datetime.combine(now.today(), exp_now.time())) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'time'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate Time Difference Between Two Pandas Columns in Hours and Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-time-difference-between-two-pandas-columns-in-hours-and-minutes)

Comment: i really didnt want to use pandas in order not to have another import, already using datetime, would like to stick with it instead of importing another module. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```py
start_time = datetime.time(int(exp_h), int(exp_m), 00)
stop_time = datetime.time(int(locl_h), int(locl_m), int(locl_s))
    
date = datetime.date(1, 1, 1)
datetime1 = datetime.datetime.combine(date, start_time)
datetime2 = datetime.datetime.combine(date, stop_time)
time_elapsed = datetime1 - datetime2
```