# calculating over partition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like so:

```
ID  Timestamp   Status
A   5/30/2022 2:29  Run Ended
A   5/30/2022 0:23  In Progress
A   5/30/2022 0:22  Prepared
B   5/30/2022 11:15 Run Ended
B   5/30/2022 9:18  In Progress
B   5/30/2022 0:55  Prepared
```

I want to compute the duration between each status grouped by the ID.
So the resulting output table would be:

```
ID  Duration(min)   Status change
A   0.40    In Progress-Prepared
A   125.82  Run Ended - In Progress
B   502.78  In Progress-Prepared
B   117.34  Run Ended - In Progress
```

How do I order it by descending timestamp (grouped by ID) and then subtract the last row from the previous row all the way upto the top for each ID group?

Comment: How do you compute the values? A from prepared to in progress is -1 min.

Comment: @keramat Sorry I meant it the other way. Its just the transition duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby('ID')[value].shift(1)` to access the previous `value` in the same `ID` group.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
    'time': [1,2,3,1,4,5],
    'status': ['x','y','z','xx','yy','zz']
})
df['previous_time'] = df.groupby('ID')['time'].shift(1)
df['previous_status'] = df.groupby('ID')['status'].shift(1)
df = df.dropna()
df['duration'] = df['time'] - df['previous_time'] # change this line to calculate duration between time instead
df['status_change'] = df['previous_status'] + '-' + df['status']
print (df[['ID','duration','status_change']].to_markdown(index=False))
```

Output:

| ID | duration | status_change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | x-y |
| a | 1 | y-z |
| b | 3 | xx-yy |
| b | 1 | yy-zz |

PS. you can subtract `time` and `previous_time` with answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-time-difference-between-two-pandas-columns-in-hours-and-minutes)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `groupby.diff` and `groupby.shift`:

```
out = (df
 .assign(**{'Duration(min)': pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], dayfirst=False)
            .groupby(df['ID'])
            .diff(-1).dt.total_seconds() # diff in seconds to next time in group
            .div(60), # convert to minutes
           'Status change': df.groupby('ID')['Status'].shift(-1)+'-'+df['Status']
           })
 .dropna(subset='Duration(min)') # get rid of empty rows
 [['ID', 'Duration(min)', 'Status change']]
 )
```

Output:

```
  ID  Duration(min)          Status change
0  A          126.0  In Progress-Run Ended
1  A            1.0   Prepared-In Progress
3  B          117.0  In Progress-Run Ended
4  B          503.0   Prepared-In Progress
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    val1=dd.query("Status=='In Progress'").Timestamp.squeeze()-dd.query("Status=='Prepared'").Timestamp.squeeze()
    dd1=pd.DataFrame({'ID':dd.name,"Duration(min)":val1.total_seconds()/60,"Status change":"In Progress-Prepared"},[0])

    val2=dd.query("Status=='Run Ended'").Timestamp.squeeze()-dd.query("Status=='In Progress'").Timestamp.squeeze()
    dd2=pd.DataFrame({'ID':dd.name,"Duration(min)":val2.total_seconds()/60,"Status change":"Run Ended - In Progress"},[1])

    return pd.concat([dd1,dd2])

df1=df1.assign(Timestamp=pd.to_datetime(df1.Timestamp))
df1.groupby('ID').apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

out

```
 ID  Duration(min)            Status change
0  A            1.0     In Progress-Prepared
1  A          126.0  Run Ended - In Progress
2  B          503.0     In Progress-Prepared
3  B          117.0  Run Ended - In Progress
```