# OverflowError when subtracting datetime columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer-overflow

I'm trying to check if the difference between two Timestamp columns in Pandas is greater than `n` seconds. I don't actually care about the difference. I just want to know if it's greater than `n` seconds, and I could also limit `n` to a range between, let's say, 1 to 60.

**Sounds easy, right?**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-time-difference-between-two-pandas-columns-in-hours-and-minutes) has many valuable answers outlining how to do that.

**The problem:** For reasons outside of my control, the difference between the two timestamps may be *quite* large, and that's why I'm running into an integer overflow.

Here's a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas.testing


dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "historic": [pd.Timestamp("1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00")],
        "futuristic": [pd.Timestamp("2200-01-01T00:00:00+00:00")],
    }
)

# Goal: Figure out if the difference between
#       futuristic and historic is > n seconds, i.e.:
#       futuristic - historic > n

number_of_seconds = 1

dataframe["diff_greater_n"] = (
    dataframe["futuristic"] - dataframe["historic"]
) / pd.Timedelta(seconds=1) > number_of_seconds

expected_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "historic": [pd.Timestamp("1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00")],
        "futuristic": [pd.Timestamp("2200-01-01T00:00:00+00:00")],
        "diff_greater_n": [True],
    }
)

pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal(dataframe, expected_dataframe)
```

**Error**:

> OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition

A bit more context:

- The timestamps need to have second precision, i.e. I don't care about any milliseconds
- This is one of multiple or-combined checks on the dataframe
- The dataframe may have a few million rows
- I'm quite happy that I get to finally ask about an Overflow error on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option may be to use `datetime`:

```
import datetime as dt

...

dataframe["diff_greater_n"] = (
    dataframe["futuristic"].dt.to_pydatetime() 
    - dataframe["historic"].dt.to_pydatetime()
) / dt.timedelta(seconds=1) > number_of_seconds
```

Comment: I had played around with `datetime` but somehow never tried the equivalent of the original implementation - thanks!