# Pandas Datetime Calculation Output

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I have a dataframe with two columns of datetime64 format. I have successfully been able to find the difference between them and put that new output in its own column. My query is how do I change the output format I am getting. The output in the new column is like this:

```
Column1 .... Date_Diff
12345         2 days 
             06:51:58 
56789         4 days
             16:30:22
```

All I need is the amount of days. The way I created the column is as follows:

```
df['Date_Diff'] = df.AppointmentDay - df.ScheduledDay
```

Is there something I can do to only get the amount of difference in whole days and not have the additional time info? Thanks in advance!

Python3, Pandas 1.4.4

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75476796/19123103) for other options. It has a bunch of options to convert to days (and if you want, hours, minutes etc).

Answer (score 1):

Try the `dt` accessor with the `days` attribute. Here is an example:

```
df['DayDif']= (df['AppointmentDay'] - df['ScheduledDay']).dt.days
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I am just getting started working with datetime formats. Much appreciated!